# Чи потрібно використовувати лапки в словосполучені - дренажна "подушка"?

Tags: орфографія

Маю такий текст - *"На важких та глинистих грунтах на дно посадкової ями, обов'язково роблять **дренажну "подушку"**. Для дренажного шару використовують - гравій, щебінь або пісок."*

Чи потрібно слово ***"подушка"*** брати в лапки?

Наприклад в СУМ-11 стаття ["подушка"](http://sum.in.ua/s/podushka) (знач.3) містить такий приклад:

> Підлогу в свинарниках зробили з укладеної плазом цегли на ***шлаковій
>   подушці*** (Хлібороб України, 11, 1967, 18);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Власне третє значення як раз описує вашу ситуацію:

> 3. спец. Підкладка або **прокладка в основі** різних споруд, пристроїв, механізмів і т. ін., яка пом'якшус удари або **служить запобіжним засобом від** тертя, тиску і т. ін.

Користуючись цим означенням можна описати що таке "дренажна подушка": це **прокладка в основі** посадкової ями, яка **служить запобіжним засобом від** накопичення зайвої води.

Отже в цьому реченні слово "подушка" вживається у спеціальному значенні і не є метафорою. Тому його треба вживати без лапок.

Абсолютну впевненість може дати спеціалізований словник з будівництва.

Нажаль словосполучення "дренажна подушка" у словниках знайти не вдалося (хоча є багато прикладів ужитку), а тексти ДСТУ в основному продаються і не доступні для безкоштовного перегляду. Тим не менш у словниках є приклади вживання слова "подушка" у схожому контексті.

У [Термінологічному словнику-довіднику з будівництва та архітектури](http://shron1.chtyvo.org.ua/Shmyh_Roman/Terminolohichnyi_slovnyk-dovidnyk_z_budivnytstva_ta_arkhitektury.pdf) за редакцією Р. А. Шмига, Львів 2010:

> Бутобетон – важкий бетон із включеннями (до 30-40% загального об’єму) бутового каменю. Застосовують для зведення монолітних гравітаційних гребель, влаштування стрічкових
>   фундаментів, **фундаментних подушок** під устаткування.

Видання МОН України "[Архітектура будівель і споруд](http://eprints.kname.edu.ua/3625/1/%D0%97%D0%98%D0%A12-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%801.pdf)", Харків 2007:

> - Розділ "Основні фундаменти", стор. 24: "Замінений шар ґрунту називають **подушкою**.
>     При невеликому нав антаженні на основу застосовують **піщані подушки** з великої чи середньої крупності піску. **Товщина подушки** має бути такою, щоб тиск на слабкий шар ґрунту, що лежить нижче, не перевищував його нормативного опору.
> - стор. 50: Рис.6.5. Перекриття по сталевих балках:
>     а – обпирання кінців балок на стіни; б – деталькріплення анкера; у – перекриття із заповненням залізобетонною монолітною плитою; м – те жцегельними склепіннями; 1 – сталева балка; 2 – **бетонна подушка**;
> - стор. 75: Рис.8.7. Влаштування зовнішнього входу в підвал:
>     1 – бетонна підготовка; 2 – ущільнена **піщана подушка**;

[Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928-29 рр.](https://r2u.org.ua/data/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%97%20%281928%29.pdf) на сайті r2u.org.ua:

> **Подушка** – **по́душка**; п. (в телеге на оси под кузовом) – оплі́н (-ле́ну); п. (непосредств. на оси) – наса́д (-ду); п. (на перед. оси) – коло́ворот (-ту); п. (подшипника) – пі́дкладень (-дня); п. буферная – п. відпружнико́вий; п. воздушная – **по́душка** повітряна́; п. для сидения – п. сідалко́ва; п. опорная – п-нь опо́рний; п. осная верхняя – наса́д (-ду); п. о. нижняя – **по́душка**; п. подвижная – п. рухо́мий; п. поддерживающая – п. підтримни́й; п. пружинная – **п-ка** пружи́нна; п. рамная – підварца́бник (-ка); п. скользящая – пі́дкладень ковзни́й; п. стрелочная – п. ви́личий.

Answer (score 1):

Згідно до Українського правопису 2015 року:

> § 124. Лапки (« »)
>
> У лапки беруться:
>
> 1. Цитати, причому й тоді, коли цитата входить у речення як його складова частина:
>
> ... Усім нам, працівникам галузі перекладу, цього «високого
>   мистецтва», за виразом К. І. Чуковського, або «благородного ремесла»,
>   як говорить Марія Домбровська, корисно пам’ятати слова О.
>   Твардовського про С. Маршака як перекладача Бернса: «Він зробив його
>   росіянином, залишивши шотландцем». Я б додав ще: «Він зробив його
>   Маршаком, залишивши Бернсом» — бо ж не сама тільки печать
>   національності, а й печать індивідуальності лежить на кожному
>   талановитому перекладі (Рильський).
>
> 2. Слова, що їх не вважають за свої або наводять з відтінком презирливого чи іронічного ставлення до чужого вислову, а також слова,
>      вжиті вперше або, навпаки, застарілі та незвичайні:
>
> Для більшості її (Лесі Українки) сучасників той дух (новаторського
>   мистецтва) нагадував «хмару, що сунулась так тяжко по долині», а для
>   нас, «на високості» XX століття, він «одмінився, просвічений нагірним,
>   чистим світлом» (Павличко).
>
> Моє ім’я враз із кількома іменами подібних до мене «во время оно»
>   оббігало весь край, було пострахам усіх «мирних і вірноконституційних
>   горожан», — з моїм іменем усі вони в’язали поняття перевороту,
>   революції, різні (Франко).
>
> 3. Індивідуальні назви заводів, фабрик, клубів, пароплавів, організацій, підприємств, наукових праць, літературних творів, газет,
>      журналів, кінофільмів тощо (див. ще § 38, п. 15, 17–20):
>
> Завод «Арсенал», швейна фабрика «Дитячий одяг», катер «Ластівка»,
>   фірма «Світанок», видавництво «Довіра», «Перехресні стежки» Івана
>   Франка, газета «Слово», кінофільм «Устим Кармелюк».

Зараз немає підстав для того, щоб брати слово "подушка" в лапки.